# Flash and ActionScript 3: change frame based on cursor's x-axis position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

If you navigate to the gallery page on [this flash site](http://www.au.movie.tintin.com/main/) you can see Tintin does as I describe. I have googled a few times but haven't been able to turn up anything. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Although, just changing a symbol's position instead of the current frame would work too. Either way, I just want to know how to do what the link shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a linear function to calculate all points given the beginning and the end proportions.
In this example, the movieclip `myMc` will change its x position based on the cursor given this two pairs: On `mouseX = 0` it will be at 100px, and on `mouseY = stage.stageWidth` it will be at 300px. Remember this is a linear function, so the proportion continues beyond the given limits!

```
function onEnterFrame(e:Event){
    myMc.x = solveLinearFunction(0, 100, this.stage.stageWidth, 300, this.stage.mouseX);
}
function solveLinearFunction(x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number, xx:Number):Number{
    //linear f(x) = mx + b;
    var mypos:Number = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2);
    var bypos:Number = y1 - (mypos * x1);
    return mypos * xx + bypos;
}
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
```

Here is some more info on Linear functions, they are quite handy to make scrollbars and paralax scrolling effects: http://earthmath.kennesaw.edu/main_site/review_topics/linear_functions.htm

Comment: Thanks for this! I think I understand it: at least enough to modify it a little. Here's what I did:

...solveLinearFunction(0,-675,this.stage.stageWidth,300,this.stage.mouseX...
{
 //linear f(x) = mx + b;
 var mypos:Number = (y1 + y2) / (x1 - x2);
 var bypos:Number = y1 + (mypos * x1);
 return (mypos * xx + bypos) * -1;
}
...

I changed the second number parameter in the function to -675 to center everything up. I then inverted the whole lot by multiplying it by -1. This way I wasn't chasing the content (oh yeah, it was for a gallery so the content needed interaction).